# Java - Тернарный оператор

Tags: java, операторы

```
public boolean contains(Object[] array, Object obj) {
    for (Object a : array) {
        a.equals(obj) ? return true : return false;
    }
}
```

Как работает тернарный оператор в java? что не так с кондицией?

Comment: что ты пытаешься получить этой конструкцией?

Comment: Дайте догадаюсь, что-то не работает?

Comment: пришел из JS, там такое вполне реально :D
ожидаю получить тру, если объект а из массива объектов array равен объекту obj, или фолс если не равен

Comment: ты понимаешь, что ты сделаешь `return` сразу же на первой итерации в любом случае ни разу не добравшись до конца ни в одном случае?

Comment: Вы на первой же итерации вернете `false`, если первый элемент не эквивалентен `a`

Comment: спасибо, тупанул, вопрос закрыт =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public boolean contains(Object[] array, Object obj) {
    for (Object a : array) {
        a.equals(obj) ? return true : return false;
    }
}
```

Во-первых,  срочно заклеиваем вырожденный случай с пустым массивом. Иначе есть путь выполнения, при котором для не-`void`-функции значение не возвращается (даже если он реально недостижим, компилятору-то невдомёк):

```
public boolean contains(Object[] array, Object obj) {
    for (Object a : array) {
        a.equals(obj) ? return true : return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Во-вторых, тернарный оператор ожидает **три выражения**: для условия и двух веток. **А `return` не образует выражения.** Текущий контекст (в котором мог бы использоваться результат) он безусловно завершает, поэтому ему нет смысла быть выражением, его результат нигде не может быть использован. Поскольку у вас обе ветки что-то возвращают, почему бы не "вынести `return` за скобки"?

```
public boolean contains(Object[] array, Object obj) {
    for (Object a : array) {
        return a.equals(obj) ? true : false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

В-третьих, `a.equals(obj)` уже возвращает `boolean` (`true` или `false`). Зачем тут вообще тернарный оператор?

```
public boolean contains(Object[] array, Object obj) {
    for (Object a : array) {
        return a.equals(obj);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Синтаксическая корректность достигнута. Дальше разберётесь.
Но у меня остался ещё один пункт.

В-четвёртых, эта функция оправдывает своё название только для массивов длины не более 1. Задокументируйте это поведение. Или исправьте его, если это не то, что вы задумали.

Answer (score 3):

Есть другой способ, по мне более читаемый

`Arrays.asList(array).contains(obj)`

Я считаю, что тернарный оператор нужно очень осторожно использовать. Он часто порождает незаметные и очень серьёзные ошибки.

**update**
Метод asList возвращает объект-обертку над массивом(без дополнительных трат по памяти) с правильными реализациями методов интерфейса List для массивов.

Comment: Я считаю это апогеем говнокодерства: лишь чтобы узнать содержится ли объект в массиве - выделять память под лист и добавлять туда все элементы - WAT??? "более читабельный" - не аргумент чтобы тах херить производительность. Инженеры оракла жопы рвут чтоб оптимизировать каждую закорючку в джаве, а вы делаете такое.

Comment: Рекомендую ознакомиться с методом`java.util.Arrays#asList` и что он возвращает `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`.

Comment: `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` - это просто обертка над массивом(под массив даже память не выделяется, лишь ссылка присваивается), других свойств класса просто нет, лишь методы, которые является адаптерами для класса `java.util.AbstractList`. Еще один "удивительный" факт, что из этого списка нельзя удалить элементы. Я верю, что инженеры оракла достаточно хорошо оптимизировали методы jdk.

Comment: хм, действительно, однако так все равно создается новый объект, добавляющий работы GC и кто знает сколько раз нужно вызвать этот метод - может он в цикле вызывается. да, потери не такие жуткие как я думал, но они есть и они могут расти. Видел я однажды "читабельный" вариант похожей задачи `((List<Object1>) list).stream().map(Object1::getField).collect(Collectors.toList()).contains(param)` - тоже аргументация была именно про читабельнось.

Comment: Просто с тернарным оператором я встречал больше проблем на бою. Есть класс задач, у которых производительность жутко проседает на базе, и там лучше код делать более читаемым. А есть где нужно контролировать занимаемую память, что бы GC не часто вызывался.

Comment: Согласен - тернарный оператор тоже нужно использовать осторожно, как и все эти читабельные штуки. Я считаю что как минимум в подобной ситуации правильнее просто выделить это в отдельный метод, где обыкновенным циклом пробежаться и не выделять память вообще

Comment: Это и происходит в методе `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList#indexOf`

Comment: Нужно надавать по рукам тем, кто в стайлгайды прописал ставить скобки в тернарном операторе, и проблемы с ним автоматически отпадут.

Comment: @Qwertiy я бы наоборот приписал в стайлгайд обязательность скобок в тернарном операторе

Comment: @НикитаГордеев если объект доказуемо не выходит за пределы метода - то современные JIT умеют размещать его на стеке, а не в куче. Другое дело, что код все равно странно выглядит.

Comment: @RuslanMasgutov, и в каком же месте надо ставить скобки?

Comment: @Qwertiy скобки надо ставить на вычислении условия и оборачивать результирующие выражения. Наблюдал ситуацию, когда второе выражение выполнялось не полностью из-за нехватки скобок, т.е. дробилось на тернарный оператор и еще одно логические выражение. Хотя на первый взгляд было написано все верно

Comment: @RuslanMasgutov, вот и бред это. Скобки только запутывают. `a < b && (c < d) ? x : y`.

Comment: `c < d ? x : y || z` (1) или `c < d ? x : (y || z)` (2)? разница между ними, в том что получается разный результат. Первая запись еквивалентна `(c < d ? x : y) || z`, хотя часто когда люди пишут (1) хотят именно (2)

Comment: @RuslanMasgutov, мой пример был примером неправильной расстаноки скобок вообще-то. Там оба сравнения являются условием, а не второе. Правильно было бы так: `a < b && (c < d ? x : y)`. А скобки у условия вредны.

Comment: Надеюсь ты согласишься, что наличие скобок в таких сложных выражениях упрощает работу разработчика

Comment: @RuslanMasgutov, а твои примеры эквивалентны - насвкидку у условного оператора минимальный приоритет (ну кроме запятой. которой в джаве нет). Вот: http://ideone.com/cP5t7T - ты не прав про приоритет. Впрочем, в данном случае скобки читаемость улучшили.

Comment: @RuslanMasgutov, я привёл конкретный пример - по стайлгайду поставлены скобки у предполагаемого условия. Тот, кто знает этот стайлгайд, прочитает так же, как предполагал автор. А на самом деле работает не так. Скобки вокруг условия могут только запутывать. Ни одной ситуации, когда они были бы необходимы именно вокруг условия, а не вокруг всей конструкции, я придумать не могу. Опять же, кроме запятой.

Comment: @RuslanMasgutov, а, кажется придумал. Поместить в условие другой условный оператор...

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, можно проще:

```
public boolean contains(Object[] array, Object obj) {
    for (Object a : array) {
        return a.equals(obj);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Во-вторых, если же Вам уж очень хочется использовать тернарный оператор, то синтаксис у Вас хромает, и нужно так:

```
public boolean contains(Object[] array, Object obj) {
    for (Object a : array) {
        return a.equals(obj) ? true : false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

PS. Оба метода возвращают `false`, если `array` пустой.

PPS. Логику метода во внимание не принимал (**а она не верна**), поправил только тернарный оператор.

Comment: только вроде как вот это `return a.equals(obj) ? true : false;` в цикле - неправильно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Почему?

Comment: Потому что если `a` будет `equals` объекту `obj`, и он будет располагаться например 10-ым в массиве, а 1-ый элемент не равен, то сразу первая итерация выкинет `false` .... хотя итог должен быть `true`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Смотрите **PPS**.

Comment: ИМХО лучше это вообще убрать из ответа, чтобы не сбивать с толку.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Ну, во-первых, уже не убрать, а во-вторых, вопрос был про тернарный оператор, а не про логику работы метода.

Comment: `во-первых, уже не убрать` - у вас кнопки "править" и остальные куда-то исчезли? `вопрос был про тернарный оператор, а не про логику работы метода.` -  это не значит, что нужно оставлять бред  в ответе

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, А, ну я про удаление подумал. Вы знаете, я вполне самостоятелен, чтобы сделать выбор: оставить или нет.

Comment: Жаль, что эта самостоятельность выражается в неспособности понять адекватность  своего ответа и его банального исправления до нормального уровня. Что еще ужаснее - этот сбивающий с толку ответ набрал плюсы.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, правильно теперь?

Comment: Внес правку, @post_zeew

Comment: @Flippy не надо самовольно вносить такие правки в ответы. форматирование поправить - можно. Опечатки, грамматические ошибки - ок. Но так вандалить - нельзя

Answer (score 2):

Млин, 3 ответа около 7 вариантов и только 1 верный и тот заклевали как *апогей говнокодерства*

Люди, ау вы чего?

```
public boolean contains(Object[] array, Object obj) {
    for (Object a : array) {
       if(a==null && obj==null)
          return true;
       if(a==null)
          continue;
       if(a.equals(obj))
         return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Если `null` то значит вернет `true`. Why?

Comment: @Flippy не если `null` вернет `true`, а если `if(a==null && obj==null)` - чувствуете разницу?

Comment: Тоесть если в массиве будет `null` и искомое значение `null` то вернет `true`

Comment: Ну да так и есть. А что вас в этом удивляет? `null` ведь равен `null` или как?

Comment: Зачем изобретать велосипед? метод `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList#contains` вызывает `@Override
        public int indexOf(Object o) {
            E[] a = this.a;
            if (o == null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
                    if (a[i] == null)
                        return i;
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
                    if (o.equals(a[i]))
                        return i;
            }
            return -1;
        }`

Comment: То же самое, только идет в составе jdk. Извиняюсь за форматирование метода